# JQuery Dropdown disappears on autocomplete click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

My bootstrap dropdown has a textbox that makes use of the jquery autocomplete feature. The dropdown stays open when I click and type in the textbox because of the below code. However, when I click on the autocomplete option presented the entire dropdown hides. How can I fix this?

```
  $('#myDropdown').click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><b>Enter value:</b>
                        <input type="text" id="entityId" value="">
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Could you please add the whole code or ideally upload it on JSFiddle?

Comment: Why do you need anymore than this? The code is standard... I uploaded the dropdown menu...there is just an autocomplete on the textbox in the bootstrap dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

I used $( ".selector" ).on( "autocompleteclose", function( event, ui ) {} );
from this page: [jquery autocomplete documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

For example:

```
<li class="dropdown" id="searchDropDown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-delay="1000" id="navSearch">Search <b class="caret"></b></a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:17px;">
    <form class="form" id="formSearch"> 
        <label class="formLabel" for="searchID">Device ID</label><br>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <input name="deviceID" id="searchID" type="text"><br>
        </div>
        <label class= "formLabel" for="date1">Date Range</label><br>    
        <input name="date1" id="datepicker1" type="text" placeholder="To"><br>
        <input name="date2" id="datepicker2" type="text" placeholder="From"><br>
        <button type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
//Keep autocomplete selection from closing search dropdown.
$('#searchID').on("autocompleteclose", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

That was it.